# How to unify a login controller that is using two different guards

Tags: php, laravel

Good day! I would just like to ask for some help. I have a Laravel project that currently has two login pages, one for the admin and one for the user. I am trying to unify the controllers into one. I managed to make it work using only one controller but it uses two different methods, one for the user login and one for the admin login. I noticed that both the methods look quite similar and thought that I could just use one for both the guards.

```
   public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request);

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('username', 'password'), $request->filled('remember'))) {
            return redirect()
                ->intended(route('admin.dashboard'))
                ->with('status', 'You are Logged in as Admin!');
        }
        return $this->loginFailed();
    }
    public function userLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->userValidator($request);
         if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt($request->only('username', 'password'), $request->filled('remember'))) {
            return redirect()
                ->intended(route('user.dashboard'))
                ->with('status', 'You are Logged in as User!');
        }
        return $this->loginFailed();
    }
    
     private function validator(Request $request)
    {
        
        $rules = [
            'username'    => ['required', 'exists:admins', 'min:5', 'max:191'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:255'],
        ];

        $messages = [
            'username.exists' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
            'password.error' => 'wrong password',
        ];

        $request->validate($rules, $messages);
    }

    private function userValidator(Request $request)
    {
        
        $rules = [
            'username'    => ['required', 'exists:users', 'min:5', 'max:191'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:255'],
        ];

        $messages = [
            'username.exists' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
            'password.error' => 'wrong password',
        ];

        $request->validate($rules, $messages);
    }
```

I tried using an if else statement for the login methods however the problem I faced was with the validators since the two logins use different tables for the admin and the users. I was hoping that anyone could help me in trying to create only one method for this login. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, Have you created a guard in the config/auth.php?

Comment: and which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Could you please tell me the admin and user entries in a single table? like in the database user table  user_type column and value was (admin or user). Give some more clarification.

Comment: @MiteshRathod yes I did. It works properly with the web and admin guard right now using two different methods. Also, I use Laravel 9, the project was created before Laravel 10 was released so I just continued on.

Comment: @HiteshPadhara the admin uses an admin table while the users use the users table provided by Laravel UI. This is why in the validation, I used two validation which checks if the credentials entered exists in the admin table if it is in the admin login, and check if it exists in the users table when the login came from the user login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->login($request, 'admin');
}
public function userLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->login($request, 'web');
}

public function login(Request $request, string $guard)
{
    $modelName = $guard == 'admin' ? 'admin' : 'user';

    $this->validator($request, $modelName . 's');

    if(Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($request->only('username', 'password'), $request->filled('remember'))) {
        return redirect()
            ->intended(route($modelName . '.dashboard'))
            ->with('status', "You are Logged in as " . ucfirst($modelName) . "!");
    }

    return $this->loginFailed();
}

private function validator(Request $request, string $table)
{

    $rules = [
        'username'    => ['required', 'exists:' . $table, 'min:5', 'max:191'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'max:255'],
    ];

    $messages = [
        'username.exists' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
        'password.error' => 'wrong password',
    ];

    $request->validate($rules, $messages);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I had to change some things around with the adminLogin and userLogin since for some reason it cannot read the string. But it worked without any issues after I changed that part.